# Find row indices at which a specific string appears in a cell array

Tags: arrays, string, matlab, cell-array

I'm trying to find a list of row indices at which a specific string appears in a cell array. For example, for the following cell array:

```
input = {[546]   'Blah blah blah'
         [783]   'Magic string'
         [1341]  'Blah, blah, other stuff'
         [1455]  'Magic string'
         [1544]  'Another irrelevant string'
         [1700]  'Yet another pointless string'
         [1890]  'Magic string'}
```

...If I wanted to find the string `'Magic string'`, and return the row indices of these, I would hope to end up with a vector:

```
output =

        2   4   7
```

... Because the `'Magic string'` exists on the 2nd, 4th and 7th rows of the `input`.

I have tried doing the following:

```
output = strfind({input{:,2}},'Magic string');
output = cell2mat(output);
output = find(output);
```

However, this fails at the second line, because when the `cell2mat()` operation is run, it removes all the blanks, rather than returning `NaN` for these cells. I can't run an `isnan()` operation on a cell array, so how could I acheive this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For input

```
input = {[546]   'Blah blah blah'
         [783]   'Magic string'
         [1341]  'Blah, blah, other stuff'
         [1455]  'Magic string'
         [1544]  'Another irrelevant string'
         [1700]  'Yet another pointless string'
         [1890]  'Magic string'}
```

just use

```
output = find(strcmp(input(:,2), 'Magic string'));
```

Or, if strings can appear in *any* column,

```
output = find(any(strcmp(input, 'Magic string'), 2));
```

The key is that [`strcmp`](http://es.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/strcmp.html) can be applied to cell arrays containing not only strings. For cells that contain anything other than a string it simply returns `0`.

Answer (score 0):

You could use regular expressions to parse the cell array:

```
clear
clc
input = {[546]   'Blah blah blah'
        [783]   'Magic string'
        [1341]  'Blah, blah, other stuff'
        [1455]  'Magic string'
        [1544]  'Another irrelevant string'
        [1700]  'Yet another pointless string'
        [1890]  'Magic string'}


    CheckString = 'Magic string';

    %// Check for the string of interest
    Indices = regexp(CheckString,input(:,2))
```

Indices is now a cell array. You can get the rows like so,
preserving the positions despite empty cells:

```
Indices = 

    []
    [1]
    []
    [1]
    []
    []
    [1]

    Indices = ~cellfun(@isempty,Indices);

    %// Use find to get the rows:

    output = find(Indices)
```

Which gives:

```
output =

     2
     4
     7
```